# Combining VUE project with .net framework project

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio, vue.js

I have a project that use VUE at client side and .net framework for server side, but now they are in two spretate projects. When I am developing, I have to open a port for each of them.

I know I can build VUE project into dist folder and put it into the server side but that is not what I really want since it is not very friendly for developing.

I'm wondering if there is a solution to merge two project into one in visual studio? So I can open one port and develop both client side and server side. Thank you!

Comment: I also recomment review the tutorial for implementing `spa.UseVueDevelopmentServer()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AspNetCore SPA services for starting development server for spa applications. This way you can use React, Vue etc. library/frameworks in .Net Core projects without seperation.  AspNetCore currently supporting React Applications. You can check [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NikolayMaev.ReactCoreBoilerplate) for boilerplate.

For Vue implemetation you can review this tutorial [here](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/1500/aspnet-core-vuejs-template)

Put your Vue directory to ClientApp folder (in VisualStudio):

[image: VueDirectorySetup]

And customize your code in Startup like this.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseVueDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "serve");
    }
});
```

For `AspNetCore.UseSpa()` more info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaapplicationbuilderextensions.usespa?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Hope it helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'm wondering if there's a way to the same thing in .net framework?